# ApplicationdidEnterBackground swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

here is my class OneShotLocationManager that gives the location for the user

when calling it from the ViewController it is working fine but when calling it from the ApplicationdidEnterBackground it is  not working but but displaying each 0.4 UpdateLocation in the console !

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    println("entered background")
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("updateLocation"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


}



 func updateLocation(){
    // start location services, here
    println("updateLocation")
    var manager: OneShotLocationManager?

    manager = OneShotLocationManager()
    manager!.fetchWithCompletion {location, error in

        // fetch location or an error
        if let loc = location {

        } else if let err = error {
            println(err.localizedDescription)
        }
        println("end up")
        manager = nil
    }


}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  ViewController.UpdateLocation()

}
  class func UpdateLocation(){
        var manager: OneShotLocationManager?

        manager = OneShotLocationManager()
        manager!.fetchWithCompletion {location, error in

            // fetch location or an error
            if let loc = location {

                println(loc.description)
            } else if let err = error {
                println(err.localizedDescription)
            }
            manager = nil
        }


    }


class OneShotLocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    //location manager
    private var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

    //destroy the manager
    deinit {
        locationManager?.delegate = nil
        locationManager = nil
    }

    typealias LocationClosure = ((location: CLLocation?, error: NSError?)->())
    private var didComplete: LocationClosure?

    //location manager returned, call didcomplete closure
    private func _didComplete(location: CLLocation?, error: NSError?) {
        locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
        didComplete?(location: location, error: error)
        locationManager?.delegate = nil
        locationManager = nil
    }

    //location authorization status changed
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        switch status {
        case .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
            self.locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()
        case .Denied:
            _didComplete(nil, error: NSError(domain: self.classForCoder.description(),
                code: OneShotLocationManagerErrors.AuthorizationDenied.rawValue,
                userInfo: nil))
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    internal func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        _didComplete(nil, error: error)
    }

    internal func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        if let location = locations[0] as? CLLocation {
            _didComplete(location, error: nil)
        } else {
            _didComplete(nil, error: NSError(domain: self.classForCoder.description(),
                code: OneShotLocationManagerErrors.InvalidLocation.rawValue,
                userInfo: nil))
        }
    }

    //ask for location permissions, fetch 1 location, and return
    func fetchWithCompletion(completion: LocationClosure) {
        //store the completion closure
        didComplete = completion

        //fire the location manager
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager!.delegate = self

        //check for description key and ask permissions
        if (NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription") != nil) {
            locationManager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        } else if (NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription") != nil) {
            locationManager!.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        } else {
            fatalError("To use location in iOS8 you need to define either NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription or NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in the app bundle's Info.plist file")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What 'isn't working' ? - All your code does is log to the console and you say that it is doing that.  Regardless, this isn't how you execute in the background on iOS - while you will get your logs while running under the debugger while connected to Xcode, this won't work when running normally.  You should read up on location background modes and see if significant location change will work for you.

Comment: println(loc.description) were giving the location lng,lat ! but in when app is closed just UpdateLocation is displayed and not the png,lat

Comment: Have you requested "always" authorisation?  But again - refer to the Core Location programming guide and the ios application programming guide on the correct way to use location is the background. An NSTimer won't work.

Comment: hey ! thanks for your answer ! yes always is nicely done in the plist.info!

Comment: i need to get a background call each 30 min ! how can i do it ? i am new to iOs ! in Android it was using an AlarmReceiver that call the LocationManager but i really don't have a clue in iOs ! i read a lot  of documentation and don't know which is right ! on stack overflow they asked to use NSTimer !

Comment: i need to get a background call that give me location(longitude,latitude) each 30 min

Comment: There is not guaranteed periodic background execution on iOS (ie. every 30 minutes).  For location you typically ask to receive events based on location change.  The most battery efficient is significant location change, but this may not be supported on all devices (See the Core Location documentation for how to check for its availability). If it isn't available or you require more fine-grained location updates then you simply get calls to your CLLocationManager delegate with an appropriate distance change setting on your CLLocationManager

Comment: Getting an update every 30 minutes doesn't make much sense in terms of location.  Either the person has moved, in which case you want to know (you can decide in your app that you only want to push the location updates to a server every 30 minutes) or they haven't moved in which case there isn't anything to update.

Comment: CLLocationManager delegate is a guarantee to get location in an interval of 30 min ? or also it is not a guarantee ?

Comment: No, there are no time guarantees.  Location is about position, not time.  If you don't get an update then the position hasn't changed.  If you are using significant location change and the person moves 1km in a minute then you might get two or three updates.  If you are using full location services (drains the battery faster) then you might get an update every few seconds

Comment: Ok i got it ! so the location change is triggered when an significant change is made? that's helps a lot ! 

is there any good example for that u know ? 
there is a lot of examples on the net and im confused about the good way  to make it !